# What is the definition of a presheaf in EGA?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, category-theory

In EGA I, Grothendieck says he is not going to bother recalling the definition of a presheaf (on a given topological space $X$ with values in some category $\textbf{K}$).  I was just wondering what that definition was.  I know a presheaf should be a contravariant functor $\mathcal F$ from the category of open sets of $X$ to $\mathbf{K}$, but I was wondering if there is anything else to the definition?  For example, do we require that $\mathcal F(\emptyset)$ be a terminal object in $\mathbf{K}$?  (thereby assuming something about $\mathbf{K}$)

Comment: No, there is nothing else to the definition. In particular we do not require that $\mathcal F(\emptyset)$ be a terminal object in $\mathbf{K}$.

Comment: If you have been reading Hartshorne: in his definition, a presheaf needs to have $\mathscr F(\varnothing) = 0$. This is generally considered to be the wrong definition (whatever that means!). (Of course, for sheaves the property *follows* from the sheaf condition on the empty covering of $\varnothing$.)

Comment: Comments as answers - again ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use the Springer edition of EGA I from 1971, which is more complete than the 1960 original. The definition of a presheaf is in (3.1.1) (Chapter 0). Of course, you can [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presheaf) [it](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/presheaf) [also](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/006D) [elsewhere](https://books.google.de/books?id=XEiLudn6sq4C&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47#v=onepage&q&f=false).